# Check if variable is in a list within a dictionary in Ansible

Tags: jinja2, ansible

I have the following tasks:

```
- name: Retrieve records from Route53
  route53:
    command: get
    zone: "{{ stag_zone }}"
    record: "{{ stag_record }}"
    type: A
    aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
  register: rec

- name: Print records
  debug: var=rec

- name: Record contains IP
  debug: msg="{{rec}} contains {{stag_ip}}"
  when: "'{{stag_ip}}' in {{rec.set.values}}"
```

The `Print records` task outputs something like this:

```
ok: [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] => {
    "var": {
        "rec": {
            "changed": false, 
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": "", 
                "module_name": "route53"
            }, 
            "set": {
                "alias": false, 
                "record": "YYY.XXX.ZZZ.", 
                "ttl": "300", 
                "type": "A", 
                "value": "AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA,BBB.BBB.BBB.BBB", 
                "values": [
                    "AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA",
                    "BBB.BBB.BBB.BBB"
                ], 
                "zone": "XXX.ZZZ."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to execute "Record contains IP" task only when `{{stag_ip}}` is in `{{rec.set.values}}`. But my `when` clause is definitely broken. It outputs this:

```
fatal: [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] => Failed to template {% if 'QQQ.QQQ.QQQ.QQQ' in <built-in method values of dict object at 0x7fb66f54e6e0> %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}: template error while templating string: unexpected '<'
```

How can I "cast" `rec.set.values` to a list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is because `values` is a `dict` method. So it has "precedence" over accessing keys. To fix this, one has to explicitly call `get`:

```
when: stag_ip in rec.set.get('values')
```